# can I create a table with numeric-table-name in sql?

Tags: sql

I have a C# program which creates data table dynamically.
but I encountered with error when the user inputs numeric data only.

Is there any possible way to create a data table with numeric table-name?

Comment: Which database are you using? "sql" is not the name of a database.

Answer (score 3):

In standard SQL grammar, table names that start with numbers are not allowed:
http://forcedotcom.github.io/phoenix/#name

You can start with a letter and then use numbers.

Note that dynamically creating tables en masse are usually a sign that you need to work on your database design.

Answer (score 1):

This works... in SQL Server 2008...

```
CREATE TABLE [47]
(ID int, val varchar(150))
```

I would also not normally do this kind of thing, and avoid dynamically creating tables.